# Angular Model Class giving error when using in Array

Tags: angular

For this project, I have created a class and I am trying to use the constructor format for some of the content on the project.

My Angular class -

```
import {Languages} from './temp-languages.enum';

export class Snippet {
  private _title: string;
  private _desc: string;
  private _code: string;
  private _lang: Languages;

  get title(): string {
    return this._title;
  }

  get desc(): string {
    return this._desc;
  }

  get code(): string {
    return this._code;
  }

  get lang(): Languages {
    return this._lang;
  }

  constructor(title: string, desc: string, code: string, lang: Languages) {
    this._title = title;
    this._desc = desc;
    this._code = code;
    this._lang = lang;
  }

}
```

When I attempt to use the class in my homepage-controller.ts I am getting an error stating it expected 4 arguments, but it got 7.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Snippet } from '../models/snippet';
import { Languages } from '../models/temp-languages.enum';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page-controller',
  templateUrl: './home-page-controller.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page-controller.component.scss']
})
export class HomePageControllerComponent implements OnInit {

  snippets = [
    new Snippet(title: 'My Title', desc: 'This is a short description', code: 'there is a small example here', Languages.css)
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am also getting the following error in my terminal-

```
ERROR in src/app/home-page/home-page-controller/home-page-controller.component.ts(13,22): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/home-page/home-page-controller/home-page-controller.component.ts(13,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/home-page/home-page-controller/home-page-controller.component.ts(13,42): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

From what I can see everything should be working fine and I can't seem to understand why the class constructor is throwing an error in the array. Any feedback is most appreciated!

Comment: Try `new Snippet('My Title', 'This is a short description', 'there is a small example here', Languages.css)`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who jumped in. I'm working on a tutorial and they didn't remove the title, code, etc from the array. I really appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 2):

The Terminal error is from the named parameters in the Snippet constructor.

Change `title: 'My Title'` to just `'My Title'` and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are instantiating new object is wrong -

Replace

```
new Snippet(title: 'My Title', desc: 'This is a short description', code: 'there is a small example here', Languages.css)
```

by

```
new Snippet('My Title', 'This is a short description', 'there is a small example here', Languages.css)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have setup the constructu with 4 arguments but then you call the new Snippet with a object like structure.

Use the following:

```
snippets = [
    new Snippet('My Title', 'This is a short description', 
    'there is a small example here', Languages.css)
  ];
```